# How to stop single variable data.frame becoming a vector?

Tags: r

When subsetting a `data.frame` with asking for only one variable we get a vector. This is what we ask for, so it is not strange. However, in other situations (if we ask for more then one column), we get a data.frame object. Example:

```
> data <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
> str(data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ b: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> data <- data[, "b"]
> str(data)
 Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

If I need my `data` object not to change it's type from `data.frame` no matter if it has only one variable, what do I have to do? The only thing that comes to my mind is:

```
data <- data[, "a"]
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

...but this seems terribly redundant. Is there a better way, i.e. a way of saying "stay a `data.frame`, just give me a certain column"?

The problem is that I need:

- to subset using vectors of variable names of different length
- get `data.frames` with *names unchanged* as an output each time.

Comment: See e.g. [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025609/how-do-i-extract-a-single-column-from-a-data-frame-as-a-data-frame/21025639#21025639).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best is to use list subsetting. All of these will return a data.frame:

```
data['a']

data[c('a')]

data[c('a', 'b')]
```

Using matrix subsetting, you would have to add `drop = FALSE`:

```
data[, 'a', drop = FALSE]
```