# Order and subset a multi-column dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I wanted to order by some column, and subset, a multi-column dataframe but the command used did not work

```
print(df[order(df$x) & df$x < 5,])
```

This does not order the results.

To debug this I generated a test dataframe with 1 column but this 'simplification' had unexpected effects

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:50))

print(df[order(df$x) & df$x < 5,])
```

This does not order the results so I felt I had reproduced the problem but with simpler data.

Breaking down the process to first ordering and then subsetting led me to discover the ordering in this case does not generate a dataframe object

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:50))
ndf <- df[order(df$x),]
print(class(ndf))
```

produces

```
[1] "integer"
```

Attempting to subset the resultant "integer" ndf object using dataframe syntax e.g.

```
print(ndf[ndf$x < 5, ])
```

obviously generates an error:

```
Error in ndf$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
```

Simplifying even further, I found subsetting alone (not applying the order function ) does not generate a dataframe object

```
ndf <- df[df$x < 5,]

class(ndf)
[1] "integer"
```

It turns out for the multicolumn dataframe that separating the ordering and the subsetting does work as expected

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:50), y = rnorm(50))

ndf <- df[order(df$x),]

print(ndf[ndf$x < 5, ])
```

and this solved my original problem, but led to two further questions:

1. Why is the type of object returned, as described above based on the 1 column dataframe test case, not a dataframe? ( I appreciate a 1 column dataframe just contains a single vector but it's still wrapped in a dataframe ?)
2. Is it possible to order and subset a multicolumn dataframe in 1 step?

Comment: data.frames in R automatically simplify to vectors when selecting just one column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025609/how-do-i-extract-a-single-column-from-a-data-frame-as-a-data-frame (you can prevent that with `drop=FALSE`). Subsetting and ordering are two different operations. You should do them in two logical steps (but possibly one line of code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `data.frame` in R automatically simplifies to vectors when selecting just one column. This is a common and useful simplification and is better described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025609/how-do-i-extract-a-single-column-from-a-data-frame-as-a-data-frame). Of course you can prevent that with `drop=FALSE`.

Subsetting and ordering are two different operations. You should do them in two logical steps (but possibly one line of code). This line doesn't make a lot of sense

```
df[order(df$x) & df$x < 5,]
```

Subsetting in R can either be done with a vector of row indices (which `order()` returns) or boolean values (which the `<` comparison returns). Mixing them (with just an `&`) doesn't make it clear how R should perform the subset. But you can break that out into two steps with `subset()`

```
subset(df[order(df$x),], x < 5)
```

This does the ordering first and then the subsetting. Note that the condition no longer directory references the value of `df` specfically, it's will filter the data from the re-ordered data.frame.

Operations like this is one of the reasons many people perfer the `dplyr` library for data manipulations. For example this can be done with

```
library(dplyr)
dd <- data.frame(x = sample(1:50))
dd %>% filter(x<5) %>% arrange(x)
```