# Remove one row from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm totally confused ! I have a one column dataframe in R :

```
temp1 = structure(list(Hamburg = c("Hamburg", "4562", "4604")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

str(temp1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Hamburg: chr  "Hamburg" "4562" "4604"
```

When I remove the first row by :

```
temp1 = temp1[-1,]
```

then the remaining is not a dataframe any more ! and I do not have the column name as well !

```
temp1
[1] "4562" "4604"

str(temp1)
 chr [1:2] "4562" "4604"
```

How could I fix it ? I would like to keep the dataframe structure just get rid of the first row !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
temp1 = temp1[-1,, drop=F]
str(temp1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Hamburg: chr  "4562" "4604"
```

The default is T, which reduces the data.frame to its smallest dimension
[How do I extract a single column from a data.frame as a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025609/how-do-i-extract-a-single-column-from-a-data-frame-as-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

An option with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
as_tibble(temp1) %>% 
    slice(-1)
```