# Display summary column on ggplot2 chart and access single column summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tested several ways to display summary statistics on a ggplot2 histogram,and found the simpler ways by using code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

cols <- c("Hello","Hi" )
a <- summary(Test_data[cols])
grid.table(a)
```

This produces nice summary table on the chart but with two column name and stat values.

Since chart is only for a particular attribute, I want to use only one column (say 2nd column). To access that, I use the code below:

```
grid.table(a[1:6,2:2])
```

This also works well except it just gives summary stat but no column name.

The structure of summary table is 'table':

```
> str(a)
 'table' chr [1:6, 1:2] "Min.   :124.5  " "1st Qu.:125.0  " "Median :125.0  " ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Hello" "Hi"
```

Is it possible to display in above case just access one column summary with column name as well on the chart? Thanks.

**EDIT**
I add sample data below:

```
mtcars
cols <- c("mpg","cyl")
a <- summary(mtcars[cols])
```

Now simply i make a visual table with two columns:

```
library(gridExtra)    
grid.table(a)
```

[image]

as you can see column name mpg and cyl are visible in the visual above. even

```
grid.table(a[1:6,1:2])
```

also works similar way.

but if I use below code to get summary stat for only one column, then visual table displays correct stat but with no column name:

```
grid.table(a[1:6,2:2])
```

[image]

My purpose is to get column name as well on this single column visual.

Comment: can you share the test data you are using?

Comment: Please see exact demo of the problem with sample data.

Comment: Try `grid.table(a[1:6, 2:2, drop = F])` instead of `grid.table(a[1:6, 2:2])`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025609/how-do-i-extract-a-single-column-from-a-data-frame-as-a-data-frame)

Comment: It worked well and my purpose served. Can I add other attribute to summary result such as stdev, counts etc?

Comment: @user7256821 You may want to create your own table / dataframe of desired summary statistics; that would give you freedom to include / exclude whatever you need for your purpose.