# Sweep function generate error about array dims

Tags: r, matrix

I have calculated some matrix as follow:

```
A <- matrix(c(1:9), nrow = 3)
a <- c(1:8)
b <- seq(1, 7, length.out = 8)
c <- rep(c(1,2), each=2, times=2)
B <- cbind(a, b, c)
C <- rbind(A, B)
```

And when I tried to multiple the last column of C by 2, using sweep()

```
C[,ncol(C)] <- sweep(C[,ncol(C)], 2, 2, `*`)
```

There appears error: Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If you're working with a single column you don't need `sweep()`.

Comment: `C[,ncol(C)]` will return a _vector_ (and dims is length 0 for a vector), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21025609/3358272. If `C` is a `data.table` or `tbl_df` (tibble), this does not happen. With base-R `data.frame`, though, add `drop=FALSE`, as in `C[,ncol(C),drop=FALSE]`. But on further thinking about it, I think RitchieSacramento is right ... why `sweep` a single column? Why not just `2*C[,ncol(C)]`?

Comment: Sorry JP, but your solution cannot work. I thought my code work before, but it didn't work out now(
Ritchie, I was doing my homework, and it required me to multiply the third column of matrix C by 2 in three ways. This is the third and only way I cannot work out.
Evans, I get your ideas, but still, adding drop=FALSE cannot solve the error

Comment: @cccbc what about `sweep(matrix(C[,ncol(C)]), 2, 2, \`*\`)`?

Comment: @jpsmith It worked! Thank you so much and everyone who offered kind help!